# Rails - escape html in helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a simple method in my application_helper.rb file, which is designed to add a link that will add some a new field to a form when clicked. It looks like:

```
def link_to_add_fields(type, object_form_builder)
  link_to type, "#", "data-partial" => h(render(:partial => type + '/form', 
                       :locals => {type.singularize.to_sym => object_form_builder,
                                   :form_actions_visible => false})),
                       :class => 'add_fields'
end
```

I'm having a problem with this code, namely that the partial that should be getting added to the `data-partial` html attribute is being escaped (presumably by quotes somewhere in the rendered html). I was of the understanding that `h()` should prevent this, but it doesn't seem to be doing so. Can anyone suggest how to escape this?

EDIT: I tried using the `html_safe` method as described below, but to no avail. I have managed to get it to escape by doing:

```
"data-partial" => "'" + render(:partial => type + '/form', :locals => {type.singularize.to_sym => object_form_builder, :form_actions_visible => false}) + "'"
```

but i'm not sure how safe this is?

EDIT 2: escaping using single quotes is no good - although it escapes the html, it outputs the quotes when the partial is rendered, which is not desirable. Still looking for any ideas on how to escape the html successfully when rendering the partial.

Answer (score 4):

Try an `.html_safe` method

```
def link_to_add_fields(type, object_form_builder)
  link_to type, "#", "data-partial" => h(render(:partial => type + '/form', 
                       :locals => {type.singularize.to_sym => object_form_builder,
                                   :form_actions_visible => false})).html_safe,
                       :class => 'add_fields'
end
```